# Default images in windows phone project?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I just finished my first application for windows phone in C# Silverlight (for which I asked a lot of questions on this forum) and I just looked at the default images of the project and I noticed that I've never seen the image called background in my application using the emulator. What is it for???? Thanks!!!
p.s.
(I'm new to windows phone, that's why I ask a lot of questions!!!)

Comment: This is not a forum.  This is a question & answer site.

Comment: I beg you pardon!! Anyway, Could someone tell me where I would see that image??? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Background.png image is the image used as the home screen tile, and that is why the default image size when you create a new project is 173x173 pixels!

Comment: All you have to do is pin your app to the start screen and it will show up with that image!

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! I never noticed I could do so. I don't have a real mobile, only the emulator.

Comment: Even if you're using the emulator, you can pin the app to the start screen to test it out!